# Is $HK$ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Assume we have two normal abelian subgroups of the finite group $G$ and we call them $H,K$. My question:-

> Is $HK$ abelian?

I have been able to show that $HK = KH$ and also $HK \unlhd G$. and in general I know $HK$ need not be normal, but in our case we have the extra condition which is the normality of $H,K$.

Comment: Take $G$ the quaternions, $H$ the subgroup generated by $i$ and $K$ the subgroup generated by $j$

Comment: Not in general, but if in addition f $H \cap K=\{ 1 \}$ then $HK$ is abelian.